# Why does doing more physical labour reduce the prevalence of disorders like OCD?

Tags: brain, psychology

This just an observation without any study backing it. But people who do more physical labour as opposed to sitting at the couch really do have less rates of OCD.
Why this association of physical work with OCD's?

By OCD, I mean Obsessive Compulsive Disorder.

Here's a study backing up the exercise and its positive effects on reduction of OCD,
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/17568300/

Comment: What is OCD? (And don't ask me to do an internet search, I'm on this website and I shouldn't have to wrestle with niche abbreviations. And how do you think anyone is going to answer a question about pre-agricultural man other than by speculation?

Comment: I edited out that question. And added details like full form of OCD.Is it OK now?

Comment: I retracted my close vote due to your edits, thank you. To improve your question, though, it would be best to have a citation for the claim "people who do more physical labour as opposed to sitting at the couch really do have less rates of OCD" - if this is just your own observation, then we can't really answer the "why." It's hard enough to answer "why" questions when there **is** a known effect.

Comment: @Bryan Krause. I can see my question was a horrendous one, I'm sorry bout that. I couldn't find any valid scientific citations backing up the labour claim but here's one backing up aerobic exercise.

Comment: I would first ask which way the causation works.  Does couch-sitting increase OCD, or do people with OCD prefer to be couch-sitters as a consequence of the OCD?